# How to get counter when inputs, select etc. change in form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, filtering, counter

```js
 var inpts = $('.map-form .val-input');
 var radio = $('.map-form .radio-input');
 var counter = $('.filtr-map-count');

 $('.detect-change').change(function() { 
  countInputs();
 });


 function countInputs() {
  var click = 0; 
   $(inpts).each(function(){
    if($(this).val() != ""){
     click++;
    } 
    counter.text(click);
   });

   $(radio).each(function() {
    if($(this).val() != ""){
     click++;
    } 
    counter.text(click);
   });
 };


 $(window).on('load', function() { 
   countInputs();
  });
```

```css
.filtr-map {
   background-color: red;
   width: 100px;
   height: 40px;
   color: #fff;
   z-index: 99;
   font-weight: bolder;
   cursor: pointer;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
      margin-top: 50px;
  }

  .filtr-map-count {
   font-size: 10px;
   position: relative;
   top: -5px;
   left: 5px;
   background-color: #000;
   border-radius: 50%;
   width: 20px;
   height: 20px;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class='map-form'>
  <div>
   <h2>Search</h2>
   <fieldset>
    <label>Price</label>
    <span>min</span>
    <input type="text" class='val-input detect-change ' value="" />
    <span>max</span>
    <input type="text" class='val-input detect-change ' value="" />
   </fieldset>
   <fieldset>
    <label>Category</label>
    <div class="styled_select">
     <select class='val-input detect-change '>
      <option value="">Default</option>
      <option value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2</option>
     </select>
    </div>
   </fieldset>
   <fieldset>
    <div class="styled_radio"><input class='radio-input detect-change' checked="checked" type="radio" id="Radio1" name="Radio" /><label
      class="input" for="Radio1"><span class="circle"><span></span></span><span>Test One Test</span></label></div>
    <div class="styled_radio"><input class='detect-change' type="radio" id="Radio2" name="Radio" /><label class="input"
      for="Radio2"><span class="circle"><span></span></span><span>Test test</span></label></div>
   </fieldset>
   <input type="submit" value='Send'>
  </div>
 </form>

   <div class="filtr-map">
    Filter<span class='filtr-map-count'>0</span>
   </div>
```

Hey, How to get counter when inputs, select etc. change in form? How to make a counter. If input/select/radio change in fieldset counter should increase, if back to default value decrease. The counter number should also works after page reload. I added a js code with im working on but something goes wrong.

**---UPDATE---**
I added working jquery code for this example, maybe will be helpful for someone else. Also I added classes that help with select the changed elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so this becomes a little more complicated if you're considering all input types.

I have written the code below as a starting point. Yes, it does do what you need it to. BUT it hasn't been fully tested and it can be improved.

See a working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/hber3q0z/

The jQuery that's doing the heavy lifting...

```
var $form = $('.map-form');
var $counter = $('.filtr-map-count');
var changed = {};

// Listen for an `update` event on counter element
$counter.on('update', function() {
  // Update the text value
  $(this).text(function() {
    var count = 0;
    // Loop through the `changed` object and count if value has changed
    $.each(changed, function(key, hasChanged) {
      if (hasChanged) {
        count++;
      }
    });

    // Return count
    return count;
  });
});

// Find all form inputs
$form.find(':input').each(function(key) {
  var $this = $(this);
  // Get the input name, else create a temporary name
  var name = $this.attr('name') || new Date().getTime().toString() + key;

  // Store the original value
  var original = $this.val();

  // If the input is a checkbox
  if ($this.is(':checkbox')) {

    // Create a function to get checkbox group values
    var checkboxValue = function() {
      var values = [];
      // Find all `checked` inputs with the same type and name
      $form.find('[type="' + $this.attr('type') + '"][name="' + $this.attr('name') + '"]:checked').each(function() {
        // Push values to array
        values.push($(this).val());
      });
      // Join them for easier comparisom
      return values.join(',');
    };

    // Store original group value
    original = checkboxValue();

    // Listen to checkbox events
    $this.on('change keyup keydown mouseup', function() {
      // Perform value changed check
      changed[name] = checkboxValue() !== original;

      // Tell the counter element to update contents
      $counter.trigger('update');
    });

  }

  // If the input is a radio
  else if ($this.is(':radio')) {

    // Create a function to get radio group value
    var radioValue = function() {
      // Find the first `checked` input with the same type and name
      return $form.find('[type="' + $this.attr('type') + '"][name="' + $this.attr('name') + '"]:checked').val();
    };

    // Store original group value
    original = radioValue();

    // Listen to radio input events
    $this.on('change keyup keydown mouseup', function() {
      // Perform value changed check
      changed[name] = radioValue() !== original;

      // Tell the counter element to update contents
      $counter.trigger('update');
    });
  }

  // Catch-all other input types
  else {

    // Listen to input events
    $this.on('change keyup keydown cut paste', function() {
      // Perform value changed check
      changed[name] = $this.val() !== original;

      // Tell the counter element to update contents
      $counter.trigger('update');
    });
  }
});
```

The code is checking all inputs in the form for an actual changed value, not just a change event. I have also included support for checkbox and radio groups.